# CPanel: how to whitelist the access of the website?

Tags: cpanel, filtering

I have to fix a website overloaded. The website doesn't load most times with a 503 error. I want to temporally stop it to everybody but me, so I want to deny all the IPs but mine.

The server has several WordPress sites within the same hosting and domain. I have found the possibily of deny the access of the IPs I want (black listing). Unfortunatelly, I have not find how to white list the access to it. Is it possible?

Comment: What web server?

Comment: @closetnoc the web server is Apache. I don't think I have direct access to it though.